# assigning new observation to a cluster

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, binary-data, mahout

Suppose I have a user/item feature matrix in Mahout and I have derived the users' loglikelihood similarity and have identified three user clusters. Now I have a new user with a set of items (same format and same set of items), how can I assign the new user one of these three clusters without recalculating a similarity matrix and reclustering procedure?
 The problem is if I use the current cluster centroids and calculate the loglikelihood similarity or any distance measure, the centroids are not binary anymore. If i use k-medians, there is a risk of them being all zeros. What is a good way to approach this? Is there any model base clustering that you recommend using, specially in MAhout?

Answer (score 1):

How about training classifiers for the clusters?

To avoid the zeros, you could use k-medoids instead. The key difference here is that k-medoids will choose the most central object **from your dataset**, so it will actually have the same sparsity as your data objects.

As I don't use Mahout, I do not know if this is available in Mahout. As far as I know it is much more computationally intensive than k-means or k-medians.